# Is it possible to get jsdoc hinting without the need to open corresponding files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, type-hinting

In Visual Studio Code I am programming a web application for which I use JSDoc. When I hover over classes that I defined using JSDoc, hinting is only available when the files are opened where the corresponding JSDoc is defined.

Is there setting or plugin which can help me so that I don't have to open all JSDoc files in order to get hints?